# jQuery focusout event fired eventhough remaining in the same parent element

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

JQuery `focusout` is bound to a div containing other elements (referred to as child elements). If any of these child elements loses the focus, the event is fired (due to bubbling: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

It is also fired when a child element loses the focus because another child element gets the focus. Is there a possibility to check for this? One could argue, that the focus remains in the same parent element and is not lost.

`document.activeElement` or  `$(':focus')` - as proposed by others - do not work for me. As it seems, at the time `focusout` is fired the new focus is not yet known to the browser.

I am reluctant to use a timeout as proposed by someone (that seems to be a hack).

I have also thought about using a `focusin` on the document-element. But I do not like global events because this breaks the idea of using plugins events are bound to.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you need this focus in/out for. Normally focus events are really seldom needed. So maybe your complete approach can be done in another way?